# AnimateLayoutChanges property disabled alpha property from child element

Tags: android-layout, android-xml

When I'm adding animatedLayoutChanges="true" to my parent Layout the alpha from the child layout doesn't work anymore:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"> // <<<<<<<

<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/my_outofzoom_text_tablet_landscape"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_rounded_corner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/movable_layout"
        android:alpha="0.5"        // <<<<<<< 
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="@string/to_far_away">

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anybody got an idea why this is so and what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess animatedLayoutChanges uses AlphaAnimation with keepLastFrame = true, which is editing your pre-determind alpha.
I never did, but maybe you can try to set animation listener and reset your desired alpha in the end. ( be aware animation listener has a bug on samsung devices it may not be called at all )